# .net or api to set spn programatically

Tags: .net, winapi, active-directory, kerberos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Query/Change SPNs on Windows Domain without SetSPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416241/query-change-spns-on-windows-domain-without-setspn)

I have a service that needs to have a service principal name (SPN) registered.  I know I can do it using the setspn.exe utility.  I'd like to know how can I programmatically register a SPN (ServicePrincipalName) with the AD, without using the setspn.exe utility.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an SPN-registration-specific API in .net (would love to know if I'm wrong and there is one). But you can write them over LDAP using your favorite LDAP API.